# Laravel eloquent where TIMESTAMP time is specific hour

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to check after my `orWhereColumn` if `planned_completion_date` time is at 09:00. `planned_completion_date` is of `timestamp` datatype. How can I check this? This is how my query looks like:

```
$portings = Porting::with('items')
->where('status', AbstractPorting::STATUS_ACCEPTED)
->where(function ($q) {
  $q->where('planned_completion_date', '<=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()));
  $q->orWhereColumn('planned_completion_date', '<', 'first_possible_date');
})->get();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel eloquent where date is equal or greater than DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266337/laravel-eloquent-where-date-is-equal-or-greater-than-datetime)

Comment: @Peppermintology Date is not important for me. I only want to check if it is at 09:00 and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```php
$portings = Porting::with('items')
->where('status', AbstractPorting::STATUS_ACCEPTED)
->where(function ($q) {
  $q->where('planned_completion_date', '<=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()));
  $q->orWhereColumn('planned_completion_date', '<', 'first_possible_date');
  $q->where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(planned_completion_date, '%H:%i')"), '=', '09:00');
})->get();
```